# Applying css style to @Html.TextBoxFor not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to apply css class style to my @Html.TextBoxFor control in mvc3 razor view. But I am not able to see the defined style applied to the control. Below is my code:

In my .cshtml file I have the control as:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.project.ProjectName, new { @class = "myStyle"})
```

In .css file I have defined the style as:

```
.myStyle
{
    width: 150px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.00em;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help me please?

Thanks,
Balaji

Comment: And the generated textbox doesn't have `class="myStyle"`? Or is there a possibility the CSS file is missing?

Comment: The code is correct, check if you are including. Css file correctly, in layout or view. Try adding a HTML `<input type="text" class="myStyle" />` to see if takes the style...

Comment: Thanks Brad for the quick turn around. The css file is existing as I am getting styles for other controls on the form.

Comment: Thanks Mate for your suggestion. I tried that too and the result is same. No styles. I tried removing all styles for my site and created a new css with only one style and tried to apply that and again the result is same.

Comment: :) Ok, check answer's @Shyju. And Maybe you could try to put `background-color: #F00;` (just in case). You could "inspect" elements with firebug or chrome to check html/css rendering

Comment: For some reason it did not work for me with the existing style name, but after creating a new style and used !IMPORTANT it worked as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that your style sheet is properly loaded to the page (check the path to style sheet is correct), possible reason for the probelm could be, some other styles are overriding your defined style. Use `IMPORTANT` to make this override everything else

```
input.myStyle
{
    width: 150px !IMPORTANT;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !IMPORTANT;
    font-size: 1.00em !IMPORTANT;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The .cshtml code looks correct to me. I would inspect the HTML source that gets generated to verify that `class="myStyle"` is present on the ProjectName input. If it is present, then the problem lies with your CSS (e.g. another style may be overriding `myStyle`).